# pygame installation: sdl-config command not found

Tags: python, installation, pygame

I used

```
./configure --prefix=$HOME
make
make install
```

to install sdl2, 
after which I tried to install pygame by

```
cd ../pygame-1.9.1release/
python setup.py install
```

but I am getting an error:

```
linuxnx:~/python/library/pygame-1.9.1release> python setup.py install
WARNING, No "Setup" File Exists, Running "config.py"
Using UNIX configuration...
Hunting dependencies...
sh: sdl-config: command not found
WARNING: "sdl-config" failed!
sh: smpeg-config: command not found
WARNING: "smpeg-config" failed!
Unable to run "sdl-config". Please make sure a development version of SDL is installed.
```

Comment: If you install using pip, you shouldn't have to mess with installing SDL manually.

Comment: Not true, actually. I ran into this error from a `pip3 install tensor2tensor`.

Answer (score 48):

I searched a long time, cause I needed the package for Python Crash Course by Eric Matthes, but couldn't find the answer that would help running
`pip install pygame`
without errors and finally found 1 line solution that worked for me

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev libsdl-image1.2-dev libsdl-mixer1.2-dev libsdl-ttf2.0-dev libsdl1.2-dev libsmpeg-dev python-numpy subversion libportmidi-dev ffmpeg libswscale-dev libavformat-dev libavcodec-dev libfreetype6-dev
```

Comment: +1, this simple solution will be useful for many even if I had to install more than 100 MB of additional packages just for the "Alien Invasion" project...

Comment: Finally! I tried every other answer and nothing worked. This finally worked. thank you

Comment: @GTK1.2.6fanboy better be prepared for the invasion than scrambling to install those extra MB in a rush as it happens, I guess :)

Answer (score 11):

I'm seeing that this thread has been around for a long time, but I think it's a good idea to leave this here in case it helps someone.
I found these lines on [a website](https://pythonprogramming.altervista.org/how-to-install-pygame-in-python-3-8/?doing_wp_cron=1597229453.3228240013122558593750) that might help:

> At the moment, 5/1/2020, you cannot install the pygame libraries in
> python 3.8 with pip install pygame, bu you can install them with a
> particular version of them, still for dev. You can install Python 3.8
> in the command line using this version: pip install pygame==2.0.0.dev6
> Latest version: pip install pygame==2.0.0.dev10

I don't know if you use python3 but it throws me more errors apart from sdl
as well as freetype-config ... Before I used "python3 -m pip install pygame".

```
:~$ python3 -m pip install pygame==2.0.0.dev10
Collecting pygame==2.0.0.dev10
  Downloading pygame-2.0.0.dev10-cp38-cp38-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (14.3 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 14.3 MB 130 kB/s
Installing collected packages: pygame
Successfully installed pygame-2.0.0.dev10
```

Nice programming time for all!! =)

Answer (score 5):

**ORIGINAL: 2013.10.25**

PyGame-1.9.1 was created in 2009 so it still use old SDL 1.2 not new SDL2.

[PySDL2](https://bitbucket.org/marcusva/py-sdl2) use SDL2

---

**EDIT: 2021.10.17**

Question and my original answer is almost 8 years old and it seems author removed `PySDL2` from URL in my old answer. He moved code from `bitbucket` to `github`

Using Google I found

- doc: https://pysdl2.readthedocs.io/
- pypi: https://pypi.org/project/PySDL2/
- github: https://github.com/marcusva/py-sdl2

And meanwhile `PyGame` started to use `SDL2`.

- Pygame.org: [pygame 2 — 28 Oct, 2020](https://www.pygame.org/news/2020/10/pygame-2)
- GitHub: [Release note](https://github.com/pygame/pygame/releases/tag/2.0.0)

See also all [releases](https://github.com/pygame/pygame/releases)

Comment: PySDL2 returns 404

Comment: @moudrick this answer is 8 years old. It seems author removed `PySDL2` from this URL. But if you use Google then you should find new place. https://pysdl2.readthedocs.io/en/rel_0_9_7/. BTW: as I know current `PyGame` uses `SDL2`

Answer (score 2):

Try this in the terminal , It should installs the sdl 1.2
    # make a temporary directory where we can download and build stuff

```
mkdir tmp
cd tmp

# download and install SDL
wget http://www.libsdl.org/release/SDL-1.2.14.tar.gz
tar -xzvf SDL-1.2.14.tar.gz
cd SDL-1.2.14
./configure 
sudo make all
```

Answer (score 2):

After I read top answer above,

I installed python-dev, libsdl-image1.2-dev.

Then I got

```
Hunting dependencies...
WARNING: "pkg-config freetype2" failed!
WARNING: "freetype-config" failed!
SDL     : found 1.2.15
FONT    : not found
IMAGE   : found
MIXER   : not found
PNG     : found
JPEG    : found
SCRAP   : found
PORTMIDI: not found
PORTTIME: not found
FREETYPE: not found
Missing dependencies
```

So I just installed these and it worked.

```
sudo apt install python-dev libsdl-image1.2-dev libsdl-mixer1.2-dev libsdl-ttf2.0-dev libportmidi-dev libfreetype6-dev
```

Answer (score 2):

This error showed up once again in Pygame-2.0.0.dev12

The solution for me was:

```
sudo apt-get install libsdl2-dev
```

Then I got

```
Hunting dependencies...
SDL     : found 2.0.9
FONT    : not found
IMAGE   : not found
MIXER   : not found
PNG     : found
JPEG    : found
SCRAP   : found
PORTMIDI: found
PORTTIME: found
FREETYPE: found 22.1.16
```

So I ran this command below:

```
sudo apt-get install libsdl2-mixer-dev libsdl2-image-dev libsdl2-ttf-dev
```

To wrap up the missing dependencies