# Cannot install pygame

Tags: python, pip, pygame

I was trying to install a python-packages by using the command `pip3 install pygame`. I'm on Ubuntu(linux) that's why I'm using `pip3` instead of `pip`. But it returns the following error

```
Collecting pygame
  Using cached pygame-1.9.6.tar.gz (3.2 MB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/python3 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-e71p_fru/pygame/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-e71p_fru/pygame/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-install-e71p_fru/pygame/pip-egg-info
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-e71p_fru/pygame/
    Complete output (29 lines):


    WARNING, No "Setup" File Exists, Running "buildconfig/config.py"
    Using UNIX configuration...

    /bin/sh: 1: sdl-config: not found
    /bin/sh: 1: sdl-config: not found
    /bin/sh: 1: sdl-config: not found
    Package freetype2 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
    Perhaps you should add the directory containing `freetype2.pc'
    to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
    No package 'freetype2' found
    Package freetype2 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
    Perhaps you should add the directory containing `freetype2.pc'
    to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
    No package 'freetype2' found
    Package freetype2 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
    Perhaps you should add the directory containing `freetype2.pc'
    to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
    No package 'freetype2' found
    /bin/sh: 1: freetype-config: not found
    /bin/sh: 1: freetype-config: not found
    /bin/sh: 1: freetype-config: not found

    Hunting dependencies...
    WARNING: "sdl-config" failed!
    WARNING: "pkg-config freetype2" failed!
    WARNING: "freetype-config" failed!
    Unable to run "sdl-config". Please make sure a development version of SDL is installed.
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Also, this doesn't happen for any packages other than pygame.

I'm using python3.8 and I'm on Ubuntu20.04

Any Help Would Be Appreciated!

Comment: Try this one;  `python3 -m pip install -U pygame --user`

Comment: @yagizcandegirmenci That command gives the same error.

Comment: what about this  `sudo apt-get install python3-pygame`

Comment: Does this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19579528/pygame-installation-sdl-config-command-not-found solve your problem?

Comment: @MdJohirulIslam Nopes, I already tried that.

Comment: @yagizcandegirmenci Thank you so much, That Worked. You can write an answer now, so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many Linux distributions have their own packages of Pygame

Installing to Ubuntu/Debian/Mint;

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pygame
```

Installing to Fedora/Red hat;

```
sudo yum install python3-pygame
```