# How do i install pygame in python3.8?

Tags: python, pygame, sdl-2, ubuntu-20.04

Collecting pygame
Using cached pygame-1.9.6.tar.gz (3.2 MB)
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
command: /usr/bin/python3 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-lva53fx4/pygame/setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-lva53fx4/pygame/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-install-lva53fx4/pygame/pip-egg-info
cwd: /tmp/pip-install-lva53fx4/pygame/
Complete output (29 lines):

```
WARNING, No "Setup" File Exists, Running "buildconfig/config.py"
Using UNIX configuration...

/bin/sh: 1: sdl-config: not found
/bin/sh: 1: sdl-config: not found
/bin/sh: 1: sdl-config: not found
Package freetype2 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `freetype2.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'freetype2' found
Package freetype2 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `freetype2.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'freetype2' found
Package freetype2 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `freetype2.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'freetype2' found
/bin/sh: 1: freetype-config: not found
/bin/sh: 1: freetype-config: not found
/bin/sh: 1: freetype-config: not found

Hunting dependencies...
WARNING: "sdl-config" failed!
WARNING: "pkg-config freetype2" failed!
WARNING: "freetype-config" failed!
Unable to run "sdl-config". Please make sure a development version of SDL is installed.
----------------------------------------
```

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pygame installation: sdl-config command not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19579528/pygame-installation-sdl-config-command-not-found)

Comment: what have you used to install pygame

Answer (score 0):

for this moment there is no official version. There is a dev version:

```
pip install pygame==2.0.0.dev6
```

but I recommend you go back to 3.7 and wait.

Answer (score 0):

Use this
`sudo apt-get install python3-pygame`