# while installing mu editor, i get error metadata-generation-failed and error subprocess-exited-with-error. I've updated pip, am running python 3.10.4

Tags: python, linux, pip, mu

> Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not
> writeable Requirement already satisfied: mu-editor in
> ./.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (1.0.3) Requirement already
> satisfied: pycodestyle==2.4.0 in ./.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages
> (from mu-editor) (2.4.0) Requirement already satisfied:
> qtconsole==4.3.1 in ./.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from
> mu-editor) (4.3.1) Requirement already satisfied: PyQtChart==5.14.0 in
> ./.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from mu-editor) (5.14.0)
> Requirement already satisfied: gpiozero>=1.4.1 in
> ./.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from mu-editor) (1.6.2)
> Requirement already satisfied: Pillow>=5.2.0 in
> /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from mu-editor) (9.0.1) Requirement
> already satisfied: requests>=2.19.1 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
> (from mu-editor) (2.25.1) Requirement already satisfied: semver>=2.8.0
> in ./.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from mu-editor) (2.13.0)
> Collecting pgzero==1.2   Using cached pgzero-1.2-py3-none-any.whl (69
> kB) Collecting pyqt5==5.14.1   Using cached
> PyQt5-5.14.1-5.14.1-cp35.cp36.cp37.cp38-abi3-manylinux2014_x86_64.whl
> (63.5 MB) Requirement already satisfied: pyserial==3.4 in
> ./.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from mu-editor) (3.4)
> Requirement already satisfied: qscintilla==2.11.4 in
> ./.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from mu-editor) (2.11.4)
> Requirement already satisfied: pigpio>=1.40.post1 in
> ./.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from mu-editor) (1.78)
> Requirement already satisfied: nudatus>=0.0.3 in
> ./.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from mu-editor) (0.0.5)
> Requirement already satisfied: appdirs>=1.4.3 in
> ./.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from mu-editor) (1.4.4)
> Requirement already satisfied: guizero>=1.1.0 in
> ./.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from mu-editor) (1.3.0)
> Requirement already satisfied: matplotlib==2.2.2 in
> ./.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from mu-editor) (2.2.2)
> Requirement already satisfied: pyflakes==2.0.0 in
> ./.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from mu-editor) (2.0.0)
> Collecting kiwisolver>=1.0.1   Using cached
> kiwisolver-1.4.2-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_12_x86_64.manylinux2010_x86_64.whl
> (1.6 MB) Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.10 in
> /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from matplotlib==2.2.2->mu-editor)
> (1.16.0) Requirement already satisfied:
> pyparsing!=2.0.4,!=2.1.2,!=2.1.6,>=2.0.1 in
> /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from matplotlib==2.2.2->mu-editor)
> (2.4.7) Collecting python-dateutil>=2.1   Using cached
> python_dateutil-2.8.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (247 kB) Collecting
> cycler>=0.10   Using cached cycler-0.11.0-py3-none-any.whl (6.4 kB)
> Requirement already satisfied: pytz in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
> (from matplotlib==2.2.2->mu-editor) (2022.1) Requirement already
> satisfied: numpy>=1.7.1 in ./.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from
> matplotlib==2.2.2->mu-editor) (1.22.3) Collecting pygame<2.0,>=1.9.2
> Using cached pygame-1.9.6.tar.gz (3.2 MB)   Preparing metadata
> (setup.py) ... error   error: subprocess-exited-with-error
> × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.   │ exit code: 1   ╰─> [12 lines of output]
>
> ```
>   WARNING, No "Setup" File Exists, Running "buildconfig/config.py"
>   Using UNIX configuration...
>   
>   /bin/sh: 1: sdl-config: not found
>   /bin/sh: 1: sdl-config: not found
>   /bin/sh: 1: sdl-config: not found
>   Unable to run "sdl-config". Please make sure a development version of SDL is installed.
>   
>   Hunting dependencies...
>   WARNING: "sdl-config" failed!
>   [end of output]
>  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip. error: metadata-generation-failed
> ```
>
> × Encountered error while generating package metadata. ╰─> See above
> for output.
>
> note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
> hint: See above for details.

I've installed python 3.10.4, reinstalled pip3 and updated it (tried to at least).
I've followed the instructions on mu's [website](https://codewith.mu/en/howto/1.1/install_with_python).

I'm using Pop!_OS 22.04 LTS x86_64. I recently updated my pop os from 20.04 LTS. After updating, mu-editor worked for a while and now I got this problem. I'm assuming it's due to my messing up some sort of code.

Any help or suggestions r greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest either

1. try running with `--use-deprecated=backtrack-on-build-failures` for
   example `pip install pygames --use-deprecated=backtrack-on-build-failures`
   OR
2. Try this command which I got from [another stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19579528/pygame-installation-sdl-config-command-not-found)

   `sudo apt-get install python-dev libsdl-image1.2-dev libsdl-mixer1.2-dev libsdl-ttf2.0-dev libsdl1.2-dev libsmpeg-dev python-numpy subversion libportmidi-dev ffmpeg libswscale-dev libavformat-dev libavcodec-dev libfreetype6-dev` Before running your commands

Comment: thanks for the comment! I tried doing step 1. Gave me an error saying couldn't find a version that satisfies the requirement pygames.

step 2 said that python-dev was missing and that "the following packages replace it:
  python2-dev:i386 python2:i386 python2-dev python2 python-dev-is-python3"
however, while installing mu-editor again, i get another new error saying "python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully." and "error: metadata-generation-failed"

perhaps i need to install python-dev manually?